# What temperature of Softmax layer should I use during neural network training?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've written GRU (gated recurrent unit) implementation in C#, it works fine. But my Softmax layer has no temperature parameter (T=1). I want to implement "softmax with temperature":
$$
P_{i} = \frac{e^{\frac{y_{i}}{T}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{\frac{y_{k}}{T}}}
$$
 but I can not find any answers to my question: should I **train** my neural network using T=1 (my default training), or I should use some specific value somehow related to value, which I intend to use during sampling?

Comment: Is the idea of temperature that it should increase as activity increases. It's kind of cold until it has "warmed up", maybe?

Comment: @mathreadler The idea behind temperature in softmax is to control randomness of predictions - at high temperature Softmax outputs are more close to each other (probabilities will have same values with T=inf), at low temperatures "softmax" become more and more "hardmax" (probability, corresponding to max input will be ~1.0, while others ~0.0 at T=0.0). So, I know how to use it during sampling values from my network. But the question is should I **train** network using values of T other then 1?

Comment: My guess is that you should alter T as you train the network. It's cold before you get up to speed with the training and then gradually gets hotter as you train.

Comment: @mathreadler Network outputs will gradually become less and less meaningfull, I afraid, because high temperature will erase difference between them. Network will probably eventually learn to ouptut values with very high differences to deal with this issue, so I won't get controllable randomness at the end of training. So, I think that correct approach is to train with T=1, but sample with various T (depending on output rquirements). I just read [source code of char-level RRN](https://github.com/andyljones/char-rnn-experiments/blob/master/sampling.lua) - It seems that I am right.

Answer (score 1):

Adding temperature into softmax will change the probability distribution, i.e., being more soft when $T>1$. However, I suspect the SGD will learn this rescaling effects.

Comment: I don't think this is true. It's more like grad_new(x)=1/T * grad_old(x*T), not simply grad_new(x)=1/T * grad_old(x)

Answer (score 0):

Even with T=1 you have an implicit temperature due to your choice of unit in measuring y or perhaps even a scaling parameter in generating y, you could normalize by dividing with standard deviation. Choice of temperature during training may depend on training set size. In any case you should validate your training against an independent data set and you may use that to tune the temperature choice (and philisophically re-validate temp choice on another set of data).